# I have a formula to determine a one rep max. How can I derive the reps needed from that formula?

Tags: arithmetic

This formula is used to determine the one rep max (how much can you lift once) for a lift (squat, deadlift), based on the weight used and reps performed.

**1 rep max = weight + weight x reps x 0.0333**

So 15 reps with 100kg would give a 1RM of 149.5 kg.

I want to derive the reps out of this formula.

Ex. **How many reps do I need to hit the 149.5 kg rep max with 100kg?**

Answer (score 1):

Letting $'1 \;rep \;max = RM, \;weight = w, \;and \; reps = r$

$ 1 RM = W + W \times R \times 0.0333$

$1RM - W = W \times R \times 0.0333$

$R = \frac{1RM - W}{W \times 0.0333}$

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The formula is:

**((1 rep max / weight) - 1) / 0.0333**